# Reserving a package name on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Application names on Google Play don't need to be unique, and it's possible to request Google to remove violating apps through trademark claims or DCMA. What's not really clear, however, is how it works with package names.

What if I'm developing "the Google app" (forgive me for a silly example) but somebody beats me to registering `com.google`?

1. Can I prevent this from happening by uploading a signed, *though unpublished* APK to Google Play? Or do I actually have to publish the empty app?
2. Can I request Google Play to remove the existing app with its package name (and allow me to take it) because they've illegitimately used "google" in the package name?

Another question [appears here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204774/how-can-you-reserve-a-name-for-an-application), but doesn't really address package names.

Comment: I've read about `#1` being the way to do it, but it still feels a bit insecure as it's quite a "read between the lines"-scenario.

Comment: @ninetwozero That's my impression, too, but I'm especially curious about whether or not the empty app needs to be published. It would be rather silly to have some bogus app for `com.google` until it's actually released.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Yes. Just make a build of the app, sign it, submit it to your account, but Save, don't Publish. You've then reserved your package name, but nothing is publicly visible.
2. You can make a Copyright claim, whether you get anywhere is another matter...

Most normal people won't care or even notice what's in the package name, so for me I'd be more concerned about the branding and whether someone else were using a copy of my branding to promote their own offering.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I have multiple developer accounts and will check that saving a app without publishing is indeed safeguarded.

Comment: "You can make a Copyright claim" -- *trademark* violations, perhaps. I doubt that a copyright claim would work without actual copying, and simply using `com.myfirm` as a package when you don't own `myfirm.com` as a domain would not imply copying.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are most likely correct. It would be nice if Google had transparency into their policy, but I couldn't find it in their support topics or forum. In my case it involves a trademark, so I would be especially interested to hear if Google would let you lay claim on a package name containing said trademark.

Comment: So, if I own the domain naifapps.com, and release two apps under package names com.naifapps.candide and com.naifapps.erendira, there's nothing to stop some other dev from coming along and releasing an app under the package com.naifapps.bwahaha, then??

What if I were to reserve the package com.naifapps (with no further specializations following it) by uploading, saving but not publishing an app having that package.  Could I still upload, save and publish an app with the package com.naifapps.candide?  Would it prevent anyone else from using com.naifapps as a prefix?