# Securing an Android package name

Tags: android, google-play, package

I just uploaded an Android App Bundle to my Developer Console that was blank (initial android studio template) but changed the package name in my `build.gradle` file.

I did this so I could secure my package name.

[image]

My package name shows up (I replaced it with `com.package.name` above for security) - so does that mean I own the package name and no one can take it? Even though it's currently a Draft?

I uploaded the App Bundle via an Alpha (Closed track) release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the similar questions like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977469/5093606 
 ?

IMO, regarding your description Google play should reserve your package name for that application.

I think you can also test it in simple way by creating one more application on your account and uploading the same App Bundle there. You'll probably get error in case if it is already reserved by first application.